# Running a WPF by creating an AppDomain

Tags: .net, wpf, security, unmanaged, appdomain

I want to create an AppDomain and run an external WPF application through it.
The main reason is security, as I would like to control what the external WPF app can do.
Specifically, I want to disallow any usage of unmanaged code.

I've run the following code:

```
PermissionSet set = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
set.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, PATH));
set.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
set.AddPermission(new UIPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
set.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode));

Evidence ev = new Evidence();
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test", ev, new AppDomainSetup() { ApplicationBase = PATH }, set);
domain.ExecuteAssembly(PATH);
```

and it works great.

When I remove the last line in the permission set (i.e., allowing the unmanaged code to run) it stops working.

How can I disallow the new app domain to run unmanaged code, but still have the WPF app run? (Btw, the WPF app is just a File->New WPF Application, so it doesn't use any unmanaged code).

Thanks!

Comment: In what way does it stop working? Any error message?

Comment: I get an error message, saying that it couldn't load MainWindow.xaml

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need the UnamagedCode permission in order to instantiate a WPF window. Under the hood WPF uses unmanaged code to access windows APIs for things like messaging, and window management.

From the MSDN Window Overview document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx

> Window requires UnmanagedCode security permission to be instantiated. For applications installed on and launched from the local machine, this falls within the set of permissions that are granted to the application.
>
> However, this falls outside the set of permissions granted to applications that are launched from the Internet or Local intranet zone using ClickOnce. Consequently, users will receive a ClickOnce security warning and will need to elevate the permission set for the application to full trust.

If you want to restrict what the WPF application can do, you might want to try running it under a different username.